# Lighting problem

Tags: lighting

I install new 12/2 wire from breaker box to a gfi outlet pig tail to another gfi outlet then to seven regular outlets then jumped to a light switch controlly six can light(6 inch).light switch is a dimmer ,everything was working fine for about one week then the can light quit working all the outlet still work but lights won't come on. All wires are 12/2 on a 20amp breaker. The first gfi show on my yellow plug in tester open ground. I have checked the wires and they look ok.I was hoping someone could tell me what is wrong

Comment: Unless we know exactly how every box on this circuit is wired it's impossible to say. Did you wire off LOAD side of the second GFI and did it trip? 
Sorry, but not really enough actual information about the situation so far.

Answer (score 1):

Some dimmers (and other "smart" switches), [require a grounding conductor to function](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/39880/33). If there's an open ground, the receptacles will function normally, but the dimmer may not.

To test this theory, replace the dimmer with a standard snap switch. If the lights work with the new switch, the problem was an open ground. Find the break in the grounding conductor, and your problem should be solved.